# How to manage secrets in multi tenant app for multiple environments (Local, Dev, Prod)

Tags: environment, aws-secrets-manager

I have a multi-tenant application that stores the data of each client in a distinct database. To access the data I retrieve the credentials from the SecretsManager in AWS where the secret is stored by giving it the tenant_id as the name. In code, I can then just retrieve it by passing the tennant id.

Now I'm looking for a clean way to implement multiple environments. But I'm not able to find a way that suits my use case. The restrictions I'm having are:

- The tenant_id is actually the Azure Tenant ID of the client and is also used to connect to the GraphQL API. As such just using an ID like "Test-Tenant" would not be possible as I would not be able to run all the code.
- Just relying on the same database in staging and testing (which probably is a bad idea anyway) would also not be possible as the database in staging is a document DB and connecting to it is not possible via the local machine (unless via ssh tunneling but then my end point URLs would not match).

What would be a clean way to implement multiple environments in this multi-tenancy setup?